# Limit the width of buttons in Android

Tags: android, button, width

I have two buttons positioned horizontally next to each other and want to limit the width of the buttons when the screen resolution goes up. For mdpi, the two buttons should be equal length and take up the entire width of the screen. If you then switch to a higher resolution, the two buttons can grow in width if necessary but only up to a maximum width of say 100dp. I have not been successful in accomplishing this. The two buttons end up being the same size but they fill the entire width of the screen. I have tried putting the buttons in a table, in just a LinearLayout and have tried using the maxWidth on various combinations but to no avail. If I use a table, I have tried stretching the columns and not stretching them. That didn't help either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You say you've tried maxWidth...but you don't show any examples of what you tried, so here's my suggestion, which I'm nearly certain should work for you:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This didn't work either. The buttons never appear whatsoever with the code you've provided. I do find it interesting though that you've set layout_width="0dp". I'm curious what that is suppose to accomplish.

Comment: If you give them 0dp, and a layout_weight, they'll expand to fill the container in the proportions defined by their weights. If it's not showing anything at all, then you have something very wrong with your XML. Can you post your full XML that you've tried using this code?

Comment: +1 works for me.  Thanks for the tip of layout_weights with 0 widths

Comment: I've been looking at this same issue, and this solution is not working for me. I even copied and pasted the above into a fresh layout and it doesn't work - maxWidth is apparently completely ignored (perhaps only in some circumstances).

Comment: I suspect different versions of Android respect the maxWidth differently, hence different people see different results for same XML Layout

Comment: If the problem is indeed version related, the code as shown does not work on my 4.2 device nor the preview in Eclipse. Otherwise, there is something else wrong with the example.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put your xml view here. How can we find an error?
Probably, you have used background image and width set to wrapcontent ? Change the source image size to smth small

Comment: There are way too many combinations I went through, so it makes little sense to paste all of them here. No background images. Just vanilla buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating different layouts for different resolutions. This is not the best way of solving your problem, but this will surely work. Good luck!